# URL rewriting and htpasswd

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, .htpasswd

I'm using URL rewriting on my website and i would like to add an authentication via .htpasswd file to one of my directory.

My website is build like that

```
/home/website/
/home/website/protected/
/home/website/protected/.htaccess
/home/website/protected/.htpasswd
/home/website/protected/admin.php
/home/website/.htaccess
/home/website/index.php
/home/website/index_protected.php
```

On /home/website/ directory i got a .htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^directory([0-9]+)/protected/([a-z0-9-_]+).php   /home/website/protected/admin.php?d=$1&p=$2 [QSA]
```

Using url like

```
http//website/directory1/protected/test.php
```

you will call

```
/home/website/1/protected/admin.php?d=1&p=test
```

On .htaccess from /protected/ directory i got :

```
AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/home/website/protected/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

And on .htpasswd from /protected/ directory i got :

```
admin:crypted_password
```

But my problem is that, when i call

```
http//website/directory1/protected/test.php
```

i never got the authentication windows, any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place .htaccess file with Basic Auth directives to protected directory.

Comment: Maybe i've not understand, but in my /protected/ directory i already got the .htaccess file with "Basic Auth" directive

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when the server is not using .htaccess file. Check that it is allowed to use that file in /home/website/protected/ not only /home/website/.

Comment: Nop, if i open the URL http://website/protected/admin.php the authentication windows open, so it seems to be allowed

Comment: Wait, so you get authentication screen on website/protected/admin.php but not on website/protected/test.php? Try adding the RewriteRule after the authentication rule. Maybe that's what messing you up.

Comment: In fact, i got to .htaccess file, first one on /website/ with rewrite rules and second one in /website/protected/ with authentification rule.


In /website/protected/admin.php i need to have the $_GET['d'] and $_GET['p'] which are given from the 1st .htaccess (the one with rewriting rules).


The test.php page don't exist, the url rewriting just convert it to p=test and send it to /website/protected/admin.php file

Comment: It sounds pretty strange to use rewrite for website/protected in website. The rewrite is the only thing I can think of, that messes up your authentication. Try moving it into proteced .htaccess

Comment: I can't, i need to make the url rewriting on /website/ directory, if i don't, visitor can't access /directory1/